# Почему не происходит переадресация в сервлете? Java EE

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

При вводе логина и пароля не получаю переадресацию в строке сервлета:              `resp.sendRedirect("QuizAdd.jsp");`
. В чем может быть причина?

jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Autorisation</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/auth">


    <div class="container">
        <label><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

        <label><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

servlet:

```
package ui.Account;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("Authorization.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(req,resp);


        HttpSession session=req.getSession();
            String login,password;
            login=req.getParameter("uname");
            password=req.getParameter("psw");
             System.out.println(login+" "+password);

        if((login.equals("admin") || login.equals("admin2")) && password.equals("password")){    
            session.setAttribute("login",login);
            resp.sendRedirect("QuizAdd.jsp");

        }
        else resp.getWriter().print("Invalid credentions");

    }
}
```

Comment: Почему минус? В чем причина?

Comment: Код ошибки какой?

Comment: Можно узнать смысл вот этой строки: `resp.getWriter().print("Invalid credentions")`?

Comment: Видимо проблема в этой строке: `dispatcher.forward(req,resp);`. Вы сразу перенаправляете запрос странице _Authorization.jsp_ (а точнее сервлету, который будет создан веб контейнером). Собственно, Вы получаете страницу _Authorization.jsp_ и все что ниже данной строки `dispatcher.forward(req,resp);` просто не выполняется.

Comment: @RomanC кода нет. При нажатии на кнопку- данные получаются и обрабатываются, но перехода на следующую страницу не осуществляется.

Comment: @notaProgrammer К сожалению Вы не правы в плане не выполнения кода, находящегося ниже. Пробовал выводить System.out.println(..) в середину ифа, а именно         if((login.equals("admin") || login.equals("admin2")) && password.equals("password")) и получал вывод на консоль.

Comment: @notaProgrammer И как иначе без данных строк...
  RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
                                  req.getRequestDispatcher("Authorization.jsp");
 dispatcher.forward(req,resp);
...мне получить попадание на страницу jsp?

Comment: Скажите, зачем сервелету, который отвечает за логин, перенаправлять запрос на страницу *Authorization.jsp*? Я хочу понять Вашу последовательность.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76505/discussion-between-vladislav-solopov-and-not-a-programmer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем, твоя проблема в том, что ты выбрал не совсем верную последовательность действий: *LoginServlet* не должен срабатывать первым и направлять пользователь на страницу *login.jsp*, где пользователь вводит данные. *LoginServlet* лучше вызывать тогда, когда пользователь ввел данные!

Рассмотрим следующий пример. У нас есть *LoginFilter* - **всегда будет вызван первым** (Проверяет, прошел ли пользователь аутентификацию. Если да, то направляет на домашнюю страницу *index.jsp*. Нет - остается на странице *login.jsp*), *LoginServlet*.

**Последовательность действий:**

1. Пользователь делает первый запрос, поэтому **не важно на какую страницу**, *LoginFilter* перенаправить его на страницу *login.jsp*;
2. Пользователь вводит данные и нажимает кнопку *Submit*;
3. Снова вызывается *LoginFilter* (в моем примере он будет вызываться **первым** после каждого запроса);
4. Вызывается *LoginServlet*, в котором происходит проверка: есть ли пользователь с такими данными в базе.

Приступим к реализации. Первым делом взглянем на *web.xml*

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>mypackage.filters.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.servlets.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Как видно *url-pattern* для *LoginFilter* - `/*`. Это как раз и означает, что он будет вызван всегда. Ну и *LoginServlet* вызывается по url-у `/login`.

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {
    @Override public void init(FilterConfig config) {}
    @Override public void destroy() {}
    @Override public void doFilter(ServletRequest req,
                                   ServletResponse res,
                                   FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

        String loginURL = request.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp";

        boolean loggedIn = session != null && session.getAttribute("user") != null;
        boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURL) || request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURL + ".xhtml"); // Эта проверка важна иначе фильтр будет вечно перенаправлять на страницу login.jsp 

        if(loggedIn || loginRequest) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
        else {
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        }
    }
}


public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginServlet.class.getName());
    @Override public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
            String login = request.getParameter("login");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");

            Database database = new Database(); // класс который отвечает за соединение с базой данных и запросы к ней
            User user = database.findUserByLogPass(login, password);
            if(user != null) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, String.format("User %s has logged in", user));
                request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
                response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            }
            else {
                logger.log(Level.WARNING, "User with such login and password doesnt exist");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
    }
}
```

А почему же все-таки сервлет не перенаправлял на страницу *QuizAdd.jsp*? Ты наткнулся на очень тонкий момент. **Я действительно соврал, когда сказал что код ниже строки** `dispatcher.forward(req,resp);` **выполнятся не будет**. Дело в том, что все фильтры и сервлеты веб контейнер кладет в стек (но это не обязательно так). Принцип простой: первый вошел - последний вышел. Первым у тебя вызывается *LoginServlet*, который "делегирует" часть обязанностей и вызывает другой сервлет (который веб контейнер создает на основе страницы `.jsp`). **После того, как этот сервлет выполнил свою работу, продолжает выполняться LoginServlet** (это, то почему ты видел сообщения). Но проблема в том, что **сервлет (на основе страницы `.jsp`) уже отправил пользователю ответ** (поток *OutputStream* уже закрыт) и поэтому никакого перенаправления не происходит (ответ уже отправлен). Правда странно, что ты не получил ошибку `IllegalStateException` (она появляется как раз тогда, когда пытаешься дописать что-то в *OutputStream* когда он закрыт).

Надеюсь мой ответ тебе помог :)